# Synchronizing machine keys in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-farm, machinekey

I have a web application which is implemented using ASP.NET Web forms. The problem is that my login system is not working well on a hosting which is a web farm. The issue is that user gets logged out automatically after 1 min being logged in onto the system.

I was told that I need to synchronize machine keys on my web application in order to prevent this from happening like this:

```
<machineKey  
validationKey="somekey"           
decryptionKey="somekey"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

The biggest question here is, how the hell am I supposed to generate these keys, or even know their values? I don't have the access to the servers on my paid windows hosting?! So how am I supposed to do this guys?

Comment: If you don't have access to the IIS Management Console, you can use an online key generator and put those in the web.config yourself, as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Regarding your now-deleted comment: with "it doesn't work" we can't do much. Please [edit] your question to show exactly what you did and what happened.